# Regex to parse URLs from text

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

> [a-z]+[:.].*?\s

I run it on the following text:

```
regexbuddy.com
www.regexbuddy.com
http://regexbuddy.com cvc
http://www.regexbuddy.com cvcv
http://www.regexbuddy.com/ g
http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html f
http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html?source=library f
You can download RegexBu    ddy at http://www.regexbuddy.com/download.html. f
"www.domain.com/quoted URL with spaces"
http://10.2.2.1.2/ttxx/txt/gg v
support@regexbuddy.com
```

I need to match the following – the bolded text only:

- regexbuddy.com
- **www.regexbuddy.com**
- **http://regexbuddy.com** cvc
- http://www.regexbuddy.com cvcv
- **http://www.regexbuddy.com/** g
- http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html f
- **http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html?source=library** f
- You can download RegexBu ddy at **http://www.regexbuddy.com/download.html.** f
- "**www.domain.com/quoted** URL with spaces"
- **`http://10.2.2.1.2/ttxx/txt/gg`** v
     support@regexbuddy.com

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

@slhck your revised regex matches almost everything except when the url starts with www.
e.g 
 - **"www.domain.com/quoted URL with spaces"**

I made some changes to the regex to match the leading www. It looks like

> (https?)://.*(?=\s)|(www.).*?(?=\s)

Can you please review ? and suggest if there exists better ways of matching it.

Comment: Thanks for improving your question; reopened. But please clarify… why do you need to match `http://regexbuddy.com` and `www.regexbuddy.com`, but not `http://www.regexbuddy.com`, and not `http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html`? There's no pattern here…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to include the trailing whitespace in a match, use a negative lookahead:

```
[a-z]+[:.].*?(?=\s)
```

In your example, this would match:

```
regexbuddy.com
www.regexbuddy.com
http://regexbuddy.com
http://www.regexbuddy.com
http://www.regexbuddy.com/
http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html
http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html?source=library
http://www.regexbuddy.com/download.html.
www.domain.com/quoted
http://10.2.2.1.2/ttxx/txt/gg
```

To further match only `http` or `https`, and optional `www` use something like:

```
(https?):\/\/(www\.)?[a-z0-9\.:].*?(?=\s)
```

Here's [John Gruber's regex](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) to check for what looks like an URL, which appears to work quite well in your case:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

But honestly, all those approaches will only get you false matches sooner or later. If you need a regular expression to parse URLs, see this Stack Overflow question: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: ♦ Hey, I'm stuck with little something, can you see the updated question please?

Comment: This is more complicated since you need to check if there's `www` – I added an example from John Gruber which should work in your case.